# How to update existing matplotlib (python) figures with sublime text

Tags: python, matplotlib, sublimetext

I've been using the IEP from pyzo before trying out Sublime Text (ST).
There is an annoying behaviour with ST that IEP doesn't have.

In IEP, much like with Matlab or Octave, the editor and the interactive console talk to each other.
Typically if you compute some_stuff and plot it in a script, after execution of this script you can go to the console and check some values:

> print some_stuff[0:10]

or modify your plot:

> plt.whatever()

which will update your figure.
Also if you run your script several times with different parameters, the figure is simply updated.
However when you do so in ST, even with REPL, after execution of the script nothing is left, you can't access some_stuff[0:10] from REPL. Similarly, you can't modify your figure. And if you run your script several times with different parameters, a new figure is generated in a new window each time instead of updating the existing figure.

Is there an easy work around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about saving your figure to a file with `plt.savefig("fig.png")`? If you open that file with your image viewer it will be updated after running your program.

Comment: Thanks. That works ok for figures (while still not being an optimal solution). But that doesn't solve the problem of interactively accessing variables computed in the script.

If someone knows a way to have ST work similarly to Matlab, I'd love to know...